# Finding Green's function of $y'' + y = f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, greens-function, sturm-liouville

I have to find the Green's function for the following problem:

\begin{cases}
    y'' + y = f,\ 0 < x < \pi, \\
    y(0) = 0,\ y'(\pi) = 0.
\end{cases}

Here is my approach:
First I found the general solution of $y'' + y = f$, giving us so far
$$ G(x,s) = \begin{cases} c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \sin(x) & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq s\\
                          c_3 \cos(x) + c_4 \sin(x) & \text{if } s \leq x \leq \pi\end{cases} $$
Where $c$'s are constants. Plugging in the first boundary condition $y(0) = 0$ gives $c_1 = 0$. Plugging in the second boundary condition $y'(\pi) = 0$ gives $c_4 = 0$. So now we have 
$$ G(x,s) = \begin{cases} c_2 \sin(x) & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq s\\
                          c_3 \cos(x) & \text{if } s \leq x \leq \pi\end{cases} $$
Now, requiring that $\lim_\limits{x \downarrow s} \frac{dG}{dx}(x,s) - \lim_\limits{x \uparrow s} \frac{dG}{dx}(x,s) = 1$, we get $-c_3 \sin(s) -c_2\cos(s) = 1$.

Requiring that $G(x,s) = G(s,x)$, we get $c_2\sin(s) = c_3\cos(s)$.

Combining the last two gives $c_3 = \frac{-1 - c_2\cos(s)}{\sin(s)}$ and $c_3 = \frac{c_2\sin(s)}{\cos(s)}$ so $$-\cos(s)-c_2\cos^2(s) = c_2\sin^2(s)$$ giving $$c_2 = -\cos(s), c_3 = -\sin(s)$$
Resulting in the Green's function

$$ G(x,s) = \begin{cases} -\cos(s) \sin(x) & \text{if } 0 \leq x \leq s\\
                          -\sin(s) \cos(x) & \text{if } s \leq x \leq \pi\end{cases} $$

Can someone here confirm that my attempt is indeed correct? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The equation in the title and in the description are different. Is it $\lambda y'$ or $\lambda y$?

Comment: @Dylan my apologies, I accidentally mistyped the initial problem. The solution is unchanged.

Comment: Your solution looks correct to me

Comment: Your solution also looks correct to me.